# Add journal name to biblatex references, journal names not showing up

Tags: biblatex

I'm using biblatex in a beamer presentation so that I can use the \footcite command. The problem is that bibliography styles handling in biblatex don't look quite straighforward and none of the default styles will actually work for me since they do not show Journal references.

I'm looking for something similar as .bst files for Bibtex, since I can have JPC and PRL, PR bibliography styles. I surfed the internet and this stackexchange but couldn't find a proper solution. Could somebody provide me a working example with a style which shows: Authors, Year, Journal?

Best regards

The following code (authoryear style) does not show journal. Alphabetic, numeric etc only produces blank references.

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[8pt mathserif]{beamer}

\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{ae,aecompl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{library.bib}
\usetheme{Madrid}


\title[]{Title}
\author[]{author}
\institute{MSE @ NTU\\
The Zhao Research Group\\             

}
\date[]{Thursday 31, July 2014}

\begin{document}

\section{Review of interesting phenomenology}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks noframenumbering]{Polaron Transformation}

\begin{itemize}         

\item The original theory was  developed by Munn-Silbey{\tiny \footcite{Silbey1980}\footcite{Munn1985}\footcite{Munn1985a}} and further refined by Zhao et al. \footcite{JCP1994OntheMunn}\footcite{Chen2011} 

\end{itemize}   
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

And the library.bib file only contains entries such as the one referenced:

```
@article{Silbey1980,
author = {Silbey, R. and Munn, R. W.},
doi = {10.1063/1.439425},
file = {:Users/Caco/Documents/Mendeley Desktop/General theory of electronic transport in molecular crystals. I. Local linear electron–phonon coupling R. Silbey and R. W. Munn.pdf:pdf},
issn = {00219606},
journal = {The Journal of Chemical Physics},
number = {4},
pages = {2763},
title = {{General theory of electronic transport in molecular crystals. I. Local linear electron–phonon coupling}},
url = {http://scitation.aip.org/content/aip/journal/jcp/72/4/10.1063/1.439425},
volume = {72},
year = {1980}
}
```

Comment: your title has double curly bracket ({{..}}), i.e., `title = {{ ... }}`. make it single curly bracket. i.e., `title = { ... }`

Comment: Titled do show up with other styles. I don't think this is a problem. Mendeley is generating my .bib files correctly. Journal names are not showing up though

Comment: Have you tried the verbose style? That will include the journal, but also more things like the DOI. The author-title style will give you the author and title (obviously), but not the journal.